# changing layouts on the same activity

Tags: android

I'm displaying charts (AchartEngine) on my activity and I want to change the charts layout on the screen \ activity (one layout will show the charts one beneath the other and the other layout will show them more scatter).

I created two different layout containing the **same id's and same objects** I need, if I'm using setContentView with one of them everything is working fine, 
Now I want to add a spinner that will choose between the layouts and no luck there.

what are my options?

Comment: Calling `setContentView` again with new layout should work fine. Can you post your code showing what you have tried?

Comment: You can use Fragments